# dotnet core project not running in docker

Tags: visual-studio, docker, docker-compose

I just installed `docker` on windows 10
I can run the following command `docker version` so docker must be working

```
Client:
 Version:       18.03.0-ce
 API version:   1.37
 Go version:    go1.9.4
 Git commit:    0520e24302
 Built: Fri Mar 23 08:31:36 2018
 OS/Arch:       windows/amd64
 Experimental:  false
 Orchestrator:  swarm
```

If a create a new `dotnet core` project from within Visual studio the project builds fine and runs the code inside the container. (I think that is the correct terminology)

So, I tried to add an existing project to docker. Basically, all I did was right click on the .sln and added docker support.
But if I try to run the project I get the following error

> error during connect: Get https://192.168.99.100:2376/v1.37/version:
>   dial tcp 192.168.99.100:2376: connectex: A connection attempt failed
>   because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of
>   time, or established connection failed because connected host has
>   failed to respond.

How can I fix it?
I tried running simple commands in PowerShell but that seems to give the same error. (`docker version`)

how can the new project connect to `192.168.99.100:2376` and not the existing one that I added the dockerfile to?

Comment: are you intentionally running in swarm

Comment: no, I think it just created it by default, for now, I just want to get a POC going of our existing site.

Answer (score 0):

Open powershell
cd to the directory with the dockerfile
run:

```
docker build -t myapp .
```

when that's done run:

```
docker run --rm -d --name myapp -p 8080:8080 myapp
```

open browser to localhost:8080

Comment: So i run the first command and got this error. 
ERRO[0335] failed to dial gRPC: cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is 'docker daemon' running on this host?: dial tcp 192.168.99.100:2376: connectex: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
context canceled

Comment: I did a normal docker install (windows), am i missing something?